# How to use Holo.Theme in ActionbarSherlock?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I was using `Theme.Holo` as parent in my application before trying to target lower versions of Android OS. To adapt my application to older versions, I have to use `ActionBarSherlock` library. But it requires the theme of the application be one of `ActionBarSherlock`'s own themes (`Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar` instead of `Theme.Holo`).

I still need to use `Theme.Holo`. But it is not possible by default.

Are there any modifications done do make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

`Holo` theme is not known to older versions of android, `ActionBarSherlock` defines necessary parts of `Holo Style` for `ActionBar`. 
If you need to have Same look on older versions (Although it doesn't look native) you can use [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) Library.

As an alternative you can generate `Holo-Styled drawables` using [Android Holo Colors Generator](http://android-holo-colors.com/) Project